# Driver for controlling a 3-phase brushless AC motor

Tags: motor, ac, motor-controller, motordriver

I got a motor that was inside an old centrifuge device. It's Chinese and does not have data sheets except the tag on it.

[image]

From this we understand the power, current, voltage, frequency, and maximum speed of the motor (450 W, 1.8 A, 220 V, 75-100 Hz, 6000 RPM).

The wires coming from the motor and its encoder (or Hall sensor) are as follows:

[image]

The red, yellow, and blue are the 3 phases and the other 3 are for the encoder sensor.

My goal here is to control this motor's speed using a microcontroller. I have searched online for drivers that could help, but all I could find was for BLDC motors. Can someone advise?

Comment: Would a commercial [VFD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-frequency_drive) do? If not, please add to the question how it falls short.

Comment: Why not, it would do. The thing is that the name is confusing me. How it's brushless, AC, 3-phase and 220V. This combination is weird as far as I know ‍♀️. What do you suggest?

Comment: Any distinction between *induction machine* and *brushless* may be blurry. What brushless machines I remember that I'd not call induction machines use permanent magnets. 220 V sound outdated in Europe three decades after harmonising to 230/400 (four already from the decision).